# Is it okay to apply silicone sealant on damaged silicone?

Tags: walls, windows, sealing, caulking, silicone

[image]

I did what was suggested and called back window installers to seal it with silicone (they left exterior sealed and water leaked). They told me it's not their job to seal the window only make it but they offered to do it. They did a bad job, they applied silicone like putty, instead of straight line and made a mess. They did not use the caulk backer foam that i bought for the gaps (maybe not important). Pictured is part of it below window frame, there is concrete sill, the black rubber is to keep window elevated in the center (something like that).

What's the remedy, there are open gaps in the silicone. I feel in a matter of months the sealant will break apart and allow water ?

Answer (score 1):

What a crappy contractor, I have never heard of a contractor doing installs that did not correctly seal. I would contact the better business bureau, and the contractors licensing board and lodge complaints. With both you will need copies of the contract and better photos also any copies of corespondance after reporting the leak.

Comment: Im not in US, that would be a good idea at least serve as a deterrent, if it exists. Here more than 400 buildings collapse each year, there are no laws for them to follow, it's all based on honor code. But I'll look into it because they making me feel bad for asking them to seal it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, new silicone sticks to old silicone if it's mostly clean like in your situation. It's not as good as doing it right the first time, but it'll still be water tight. If it's old silicone with a layer of soap scum and mold like in a shower it's best to cut out as much as possible and start over.

If the air gaps are only at the black window shim, then yes just apply new clear silicone sealant over the old.

If you have air gaps everywhere, you might want to remove their silicone and start over. The backer rod helps to fill the gap and make good adhesion to both surfaces, you can do it without it but it's easier to make a good seal that lasts longer with it.

Comment: How does someone remove silicone? There is still the interior to do but I stopped them after seeing the mess on outside. My hands are covered in it as well. There are alternatives to silicone I plan to use for interior like lexel synthetic rubber sealant, that are can be applied over each other, would that be a good idea?   Or should I leave interior open in case water leaks from outside through the broken silicone and needs an exit?